# How to use jupyter notebook in a local tfx docker image?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tfx

I have a windows laptop where I have WSL2 installed. In that I have installed docker and successfully run the docker installation of TFX.

I am not sure on how to customize the code and run it like we see in the example Google Colab Notebook ([Colab example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/docs/tutorials/tfx/components_keras.ipynb#scrollTo=PyXjuMt8f-9u)). I want to make this setup locally.

Comment: share details further of document that you have used to refer or github repo or docker image uri.

Comment: This is the link I have used - https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker But it didn't specify how to customize the code or run the notebook inside the docker

Comment: I think you are asking about how to code a model that TFX can serve ?

Comment: Can you take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33638070/11530462) as a reference, which is proposed in a similar question related to `Tensorflow` docker container and let us know if it helps? Thanks!