# TensorFlow installation on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

When I try to install TensorFlow Google's Machine Learning library on Ubunto using command :

```
$ pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

i keep getting this error

```
tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Storing debug log for failure in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

I am using pip installed on my machine and have **python 2.7** installed on the machine as well

**vmware image info :**

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Can anyone please help me to solve this error?

Comment: 1- Please copy logs from /home/user/.pip/pip.log to your question to better identify it, 2- use virtualenv to better handling dependencies (it's not solution but tip) 3- why you say vmware?? did you installed ubuntu on a Virtual machine? As far as I heard TF doesn't work on VM, if you are on windows you can use Docker: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33618580/1973820

Comment: TensorFlow does work on VMWare Workstaion, but you cannot use the GPU.

Comment: Are you sure TensorFlow does not work on VMWare Workstation ? i have copy pip.log on below comment please take a look, i want to work on vmware and yup i have installed ubuntu on a Virtual machine is there any way i can use this library on vmware image ?

Answer (score 0):

Use super user for installation.

`$ sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

This worked for me.

Comment: i tried but it didn't work :( keep getting error :    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-gbFrva-build/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-gbFrva-build/setup.py'

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow works fine for me with VMware & Ubuntu. Please try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply :) i tried but now keep getting this errorr : root@ubuntu:/home/user/Downloads# sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: When i run above pip install cmd i keep getting this error : 
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-ZtDNlv-build/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-ZtDNlv-build/setup.py'