# Cannot import name NotFittedError on Ubuntu

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, skflow

When i try to run titanic.py script of TensorFlow and Scikit Flow example on TensorFlow i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "titanic.py", line 10, in <module>
    import skflow
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/skflow/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/skflow/estimators/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/skflow/estimators/base.py", line 25, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name NotFittedError
```

I am using pip, python 2.7.9 and Ubuntu 15

Can anyone please help me to solve this error?

Comment: Do you need to repost the essentially same installation problem every day? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875887/tensorflow-installation-on-ubuntu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853713/tensorflow-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: I think this is a legitimate bug in skflow. I've opened a GitHub issue to track it: https://github.com/google/skflow/issues/47

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** This has now been [fixed](https://github.com/google/skflow/commit/35862b95ffeab2d0d741f0489ae5dcf51436c713) in skflow. Upgrading to the latest version of skflow will fix the issue.

The offending import is in [`skflow/estimators/base.py`](https://github.com/google/skflow/blob/5dbcc5afdb94675ab019ea08658c9a16b8db1162/skflow/estimators/base.py#L25):

```
from sklearn.utils.validation import NotFittedError
```

It looks like this class was moved in a (relatively) [recent commit to scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/e3afc0e8c9de522324a2f0cf0f7a17fee5147195). It would probably be easiest to downgrade to a previous version of scikit-learn (e.g. the 0.17 release seems to be compatible). If you're feeling adventurous, you could try editing line 25 of `"build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/skflow/estimators/base.py"` to read:

```
from sklean.exceptions import NotFittedError
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **learn to debug such problems yourself**.

See: every installation is a bit different. There are hundreds of packages installed, and apparently you have a **version conflict**. But *we* do not have access to your computer, and we cannot tell which versions you have installed.

You are missing the import `NotFittedError`

Now you need to:

1. find out **where** it is imported (the error message is very helpful there)
2. where it is imported *from* (you need to look at the file on *your* computer...)
3. figure out why this is not found
4. find out when `NotFittedError` was added or removed

As far as I can tell, your tensorflow version is incompatible with your sklearn version.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade sklearn
```

fixed the problem