# Error when importing TensorFlow in Python on Windows

Tags: python, pip, tensorflow

I am running Python 2.7.10 and I successfully installed TensorFlow, using `pip install 
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl`.

When I run the `python` interpreter and attempt to import the `tensorflow` module, I get the following error:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Or\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Or\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.client_lib import *
  File "C:\Users\Or\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\client_lib.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.session import InteractiveSession
  File "C:\Users\Or\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 11, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as tf_session
  File "C:\Users\Or\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Or\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use pip to install tensorflow

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

If you are trying to install on windows , you will have to have python3.5 x64 bit and along with that you need to install  Visual C++ 2015 redistributable (x64 version) to be able to import tensorflow

Comment: Thanks so much. I had tensorflow installed and the version was 0.12.1. But still had problem. Installing the one in this answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the paths in the output, it looks like you are trying to run TensorFlow on Windows. The package that you have installed is a Mac OS X binary distribution of TensorFlow.

Unfortunately, Windows is [not currently supported by TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33618580/3574081), and it is unlikely to be supported before its build system (Bazel) adds Windows support. There is some discussion of progress towards a Windows version on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17), and an [unsupported contribution that builds TensorFlow using CMake on Windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/728).