# TensorFlow in Visual Studio 2015, using Canopy as the Python environment

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tensorflow, canopy

I followed the instructions on [this page](https://discussions.udacity.com/t/windows-tensorflow-and-visual-studio-2015/45636) and managed to install [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) via pip within Visual Studio 2015. My Python environment runs in [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/). The installation was successful. I refreshed the DB, and auto-completion via IntelliSense was available when I wrote the following line:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
```

However, when I run it in the REPL, I see the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import *
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
        from tensorflow import contrib
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from tensorflow.contrib import layers
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\layers\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
        from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers import *
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\layers\python\layers\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
        from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers.initializers import *
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\layers\python\layers\initializers.py", line 24, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.ops import random_ops
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\random_ops.py", line 23, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 39, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.framework import versions
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\versions.py", line 22, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
import _pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow
```

Can anyone shed some light on why I get the message `ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow` even though the installation of `TensorFlow` took place without a hiccup? Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of TensorFlow does not support running on Windows. In particular, the PIP packages available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) are for Linux and Mac OS X only: they include a native compiled library called `_pywrap_tensorflow` that has not been compiled for Windows.

As [suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33618580/3574081), you can run TensorFlow on Windows using a Docker container. There is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17) concerning better Windows support, but this will depend on Bazel adding support for Windows build (currently [targeted](http://bazel.io/roadmap.html) for later this year).