# TensorFlow setup on window

Tags: tensorflow

I am starting to do TensorFlow for my project but sadly I use Window 32bit. On the website they showed us how to install on Linux or iOS could anyone know how to setup on Windows.

Thanks very much.

Comment: This question has been [answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616094/tensorflow-is-it-or-will-it-sometime-soon-be-compatible-with-a-windows-work). TensorFlow development is currently only supported on Linux and Mac OS X, and binaries are only provided for 64-bit architectures. You might try using a virtual machine from a cloud provider to try TensorFlow.

Answer (score 1):

The best way or the only way for you is to using Pre-built Docker container with TensorFlow. To get started with TensorFlow quickly and work on your project, follow the instructions in following links:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md

Comment: I checked Docker and It require 64bit as well

Answer (score 0):

I set up my project on clound9, It run on Unbuntu. It is not great as destop but could be used anyway. 
Thanks