# Install tensorflow on Windows with anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow

I am trying to install Tensorflow on my Windows PC. Since I have already install and used Anaconda on Python (3.5), I have followed the instructions https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-environment-installation .

After the creation of the conda environment called tensorflow, I have tested my installation with:

```
$ python
Import tensorflow as tf
```

But I got the error :

```
ImportError: no module named 'tensorflow'
```

Does anyone know what I missed?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Since TensorFlow 0.12, we have published packages for Windows. You can install the CPU-only version with the following command:

```
C:\> pip install tensorflow
```

…and the GPU-accelerated version with:

```
C:\> pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Note that you will need the **64-bit** version of Python 3.5 installed for the above commands to work.

---

TensorFlow is [not currently supported on Windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17), and none of the official binary packages work on Windows. We are currently working on adding support for Windows, but this effort is in the early stages.

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33616094/3574081) for suggestions on how to run TensorFlow using Docker or Bash for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to activate the virtual environment that TensorFlow was installed in. When you activate the virtual environment, it will appear in parenthesis in your command prompt, like in the example tutorial:

```
$ source activate tensorflow
(tensorflow)$  # Your prompt should change
```

The source command only works on Linux/Mac as far as I'm aware, so for windows you'll have to follow the instructions here:

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate

In general, the script file that handles the activation is location in `[your_environment]/bin/activate` if you're curious about what it does.

So basically the tensorflow files are installed inside this environment folder, and Python won't be able to find them unless this folder is added to the PATH where it searches for libraries, and this is essentially what activating the environment does!

Answer (score 2):

The above provided steps will install the TensorFlow in your Windows System but still you might face problem in making it available in your Jupyter notebook - hence integrating steps from different places together to have a complete solution:

How to install Tensorflow in Anaconda environment on windows 10
1)  Download and install Anaconda 3.6 (3.5 and above) in your system from Anaconda site.
2)  Restart your system
3)  Create virtual environment by following command:
conda create -n tensorflow

4)  Activate the virtual environment

C:> activate tensorflow

(tensorflow)C:>  # Your prompt should change 
[TensorFlow in anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BvXp.png)
5)  Following steps should start installing Tensorflow in virtual environment

(tensorflow)C:>  conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
6)  Now you may enter in python and work on tensorflow
(tensorflow)C:> python

7)  But if you like to work on Tensorflow on Jupyter notebook you need to setup the karnel for your virtual environment in following steps:
a)  Install the ipython kernel module into your virtualenv

## activate your virtualenv, if you haven't already

pip install ipykernel

b)  Now run the kernel "self-install" script:
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name

Replacing the --name parameter as appropriate. In my case it is tensorflow

c)  You should now be able to see your kernel in the IPython notebook menu: Kernel -> Change kernel and be able so switch to it (you may need to refresh the page before it appears in the list). IPython will remember which kernel to use for that notebook from then on.

8)  Test the tensorflow with following program you should see  “Hello, TensorFlow!”

```
import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use pip to install tensorflow

1. Install python 3.5 x64
2. Install tensorflow using pip

   pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
3. Install  Visual C++ 2015 redistributable (x64 version) to be able to import tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow installation using Conda:

1. Install Anaconda3-4.2.0 X64 (I ran into issue with latest release 4.3.0)
2. Upgrade conda version 4.2.9-->4.2.11 (again, ran into some issues with conda 4.2.9)

   conda install conda=4.2.11
3. create environment

   conda create -n tf python=3.5
4. activate tf
5. conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

try installing tensorflow in conda

open anaconda prompt
and type this

`conda install tensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (with spyder which is optional), typing in the anaconda prompt, on Windows 7:

```
conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5
conda activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow 
conda install spyder
spyder
```

To exit the virtual environment:

```
conda deactivate
```

To restart the virtual environment:

```
conda activate tensorflow
spyder
```