# Tensorflow installation on python 3.4, windows

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.4

I'm new to tensorflow and I'm having some problems with the installation. I searched through the official website, without any success. My computer runs on windows, with python version 3.4. None of the sources on the internet seemed to have any command lines for this specific case.

I would greatly appreciate your help:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install tensorflow on Windows with anaconda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522676/install-tensorflow-on-windows-with-anaconda)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install 2 Anacondas (Python 2.7 and 3.4) on Mac OS 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-7-and-3-4-on-mac-os-10-9)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they added support for python 3.5 only,
But lately they added support for python 3.6 as well.
The only way i can see is that you would have to upgrade, I'm not such a pro with this but that's all i know because i had an import problem with tensorflow which i haven't been able to solve since

Answer (score -2):

You can get the full instructions at [Install TF on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)
I hope you already installed python3 and pip3, if not [follow](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation)

```
C:\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```