# Creating simple Android app using android studio and tensorflow

Tags: android, windows, tensorflow

**Update 1**

I have installed the official WIN package located at PyPi repository

Just to make sure I did not miss anything, I downloaded the .whl file manually, renamed it to .zip, opened and listed all the files and directories inside this package. There is nothing related to android.

---

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616094/is-tensorflow-compatible-with-a-windows-workflow), there is now a support of TensorFlow for Windows. I installed it using the instructions provided as part of Anaconda, and it works. 
However, I can't seem to find information about developing an application with TensorFlow for Android in Windows, by using Android Studio.

Currently I tried:

1. Downloaded the [Android example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) from the main branch (which is for Linux), opened it in Android Studio. The following line doesn't work: `import org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface;`. I can't guess where to import the libraries. I've tried to read the documentation in [readme.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/README.md), but it looks very Linux oriented, `.sh` scripts and etc.
2. Found the path of TensorFlow installation in Windows, 
   `C:\Program Files\Miniconda2\envs\py35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\android\java`, but it is completely empty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the Android example, originally targeted for Linux, has not been updated to work on Windows.  The TensorFlow update that supports Windows was just released last week.